# why is adding subdepth package makes lstlisting give Matlab error loading file?

Tags: listings, breqn, matlab-prettifier

If I have a dollar each time I find a conflict between Latex packages I would be a rich man.

I added `\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}` and now I am starting to get errors from `matlab-prettifier` when reading some Matlab code.

If I remove `subdepth` the error goes away. If I keep `subdepth` but remove `breqn` the error goes away also.  But I'd like to use both these three packages in the same Latex file.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{breqn}   %do not use this with tex4ht.  added 4/2/16
\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth} %added 4/29/16 to lower subscript
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
J = 8*u1-4
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The error is  pdflatex foo.tex

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subdepth/subdepth.sty) (./foo.aux
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
l.10 J = 8*u1-4

?
```

I can fix this by changing my Matlab code, from `J = 8*u1-4` to `J = 8*u1+4` but this will make my Matlab code produce wrong results, and I'd like to keep Matlab code as is, but still load it in Latex.

File list

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
matlab-prettifier.sty    2014/06/19 v0.3 A package for prettyprinting Matlab so
urce code
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
listings.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 lstmisc.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2015/06/04 1.6 listings configuration
   breqn.sty    2015/08/11 v0.98d Breaking equations
   expl3.sty    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2015/12/20 v6326 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2015/11/11 v6250 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
flexisym.sty    2015/08/11 v0.98d Make math characters macros
  cmbase.sym    2007/12/19 v0.92
mathstyle.sty    2015/08/11 v0.98d Tracking mathstyle implicitly
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
subdepth.sty    2007/09/02 v0.1 Unify subscript depths
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

TL 2015

Comment: Well, you're loading the mother of all package conflicts, that is, `breqn`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Sure, but I am not doing any math! I am just reading Matlab code, so why would breqn conflict with subdepth with lstlisting? But I admit I have no idea what these packages do under the cover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `subdepth` package changes some `\fontdimen` parameters for the math fonts and it has to do it when those fonts are first loaded. In your case, the first loading happens during initialization of `lstlisting` and the combination between this step, the needed setup for `subdepth` and the presence of `breqn` that changes the meaning of *all* characters in math, breaks.

If you have a formula before `lstlisting`, this doesn't happen, because `subdepth` does its work at font initialization. So adding

```
\sbox0{$$}
```

just after `\begin{document}` will help.

Be careful that you need to load math fonts in advance also when doing font size changes such as `\footnotesize` (if you have `lstlisting` in that context, of course).

Comment: And, please, nobody complain for `$$`, as that's a *legitimate* use.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to